# Combinatorics-set of divisors

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

It is given to me that r, s and t are prime numbers and that p, q are two positive integers such that the LCM of p and q is $$N=r^2t^4s^2  $$ and we want to find the numer of ordered pairs (p, q).

Here since LCM of (p, q)  is N then both the numbers must be divisors of N.  If we calculate the total number of divisors of N we get 45 divisors which means that our (p, q) belongs to a set of these 45 divisors. Hence number of ways of choosing the two numbers are C(45,2) and then we arrange them in 2! ways thus getting

$$ \binom{45 } { 2 }  \cdot 2!$$ But my answer deviates completely from the actualy answet which truly implies that maybe my whole method is wrong.  Can anybody help me in this problem?

Comment: See that r and $r^2$ are both divisors but their lcm is not $N$

Answer (score 1):

We have that $p$ and $q$ are two positive integers whose LCM is $r^2s^4t^2$. This first of all means that neither $p$  nor $q$ can have any prime factor besides $r, s$ and $t$.  So each of them is a product of powers of some of these three primes.  We can therefore write $p, q$  in the form

$$p = r^a s^b t^c    \text{  and   }   q = r^u s^v t^w  ...(1)$$
where $a, b, c, u, v, w$ are non-negative integers. Then the LCM, say $e$, of $p$ and $q$ is given by $$e = r^i  s^j  t^k ...(2)$$
where $i = \max\{a, u\}, j = \max\{b, v\}$  and $ k = \max\{c, w\} ...(3)$

---

The problem is now reduced to finding the  number  of  triplets  of  ordered  pairs  of  the  form $ \{(a, u), (b, v), (c, w)\}$ where $a, b, c, u, v, w$ are non-negative integers that satisfy $$\max\{a, u\} = 2,       \max\{b, v\} = 4 \text{  and  } \max\{c, w\} = 2 ...(4)$$ Let us see in how many ways the first entry of this triplet, viz., $(a, u)$ can be formed.  We want at least one of $a$ and $u$ to equal $2$.  If we let $a = 2$, then the possible values of $u$ are $0, 1$ and $2$.  These are three possibilities.

Similarly, with $u  = 2$  there will be three possibilities, viz. $a = 0, 1$ or $2$. So, in all the first ordered pair $(a, u)$ can be formed in $6$  ways. But the possibility $(2, 2)$ has been counted twice.  So, the number of ordered pairs of the type $(a, u)$ that satisfy the first requirement in $(4)$ is $5$ and not $6$.

By an analogous reasoning, the number of ordered pairs of the form $(b, v)$ which satisfy the second requirement in $(4)$ is $2 × 5 − 1=9$  while  that of ordered pairs of the type $(c, w)$ satisfying the third requirement in $(4)$ is $5$.  But the ways these three ordered pairs are formed are completely independent of each other.  So the total number of triplets of  ordered pairs  of the  form $\{(a, u), (b, v), (c, w)\}$ where  $a, b, c, u, v, w$  are non-negative integers that satisfy $(4)$ is $5\times 9\times 5 = 225$. Hope it helps.

Comment: Slightly simpler: the number of pairs $(a,u)$ with $\max\{a,u\}=2$ is $3^2-2^2,$ the number of pairs with $\max\{a,u\}\le2$ minus the number of pairs with $\max\{a,u\}\le1.$ So the answer is $$(3^2-2^2)(5^2-4^2)(3^2-2^2)=5\cdot9\cdot5=25.$$